# Python finds path to a file, yet says the file doesn't exist when I check for it?

Tags: python, file

I'm writing code for a school task which wants me iterate through 1000 .txt files and locate numbers in them and add them to a list. Repeated numbers should not be added. I had some issues with the iterations, with python saying the files doesn't exist, so I wanted to test it in a singular instance with one file:

```
print(os.path.abspath('number_000.txt'))
```

which returned the path as expected.
Yet when I try:

```
print(os.path.exists('number_000.txt'))
```

It returns False, which doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone explain?

Comment: What does `print(os.path.exists(os.path.abspath('number_000.txt')))` return?

Comment: To be clear, `os.path.abspath` does not require the file to exist.  It simply takes a string that represents a relative path and returns a string representing an equivalent absolute path.

Comment: @JNevill print(os.path.exists(os.path.abspath('number_000.txt'))) also returns False.